# How to edit Charts in Google Spreadsheet with Google SpreadSheet API in VB

Tags: vb.net, api, charts, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet on my Google Account and I have some code which edits cells in this spreadsheet. Now I'm looking for a way to edit and(/or) make a new Chart in the worksheet I'm working on. I'm using the [Google Spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) to edit the cells.
I did some hours of research on this topic but I just can't find how it would work. My understanding is that it is impossible with this API to work with charts. Is this correct?
I also found something about a [Visualization api](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=en), but I can't figure out how to get this to work in vb, let alone how to make sure the chart I create would end up in my spreadsheet.

I want to use this chart on my own website, and I don't want to have to run the code before the graph updates. In other words, when I change the information in the cells manually via my spreadsheet I want these numbers to end up in my chart. I only want to change the chart via my code when I need to add a row or column to the chart.

Lastly, I've also read it is not possible at all to edit charts in a spreadsheet via a program. If so, I'd like to say to Google:  WHY NOT!! AARGH. And maybe someone can suggest an other way to automatically update a chart which I can place on my website. (Again I want a live representation of the spreadsheet and the code I'm creating will only be run once a day if at all).

Thanks you so much for your time!

Comment: Some suggestions to improve your question: provide sample code of what you have tried; provide links to sources that you understand to state that what you want to do is impossible; third paragraph is separate more general question and might be better for a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Google have Script inside the Spreadsheets that can do that for you.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/